# Mongoose aggregate throws error when zero match

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to aggregate a field in mongodb based on some conditions. This works fine when there's at least single match, but it throws error otherwise. I want to the aggregated value as 0 when there's no match. What need to be modified in below code?

Note: `fromDate` and `toDate` passed through API Payload.

> "errorMesssage": "Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined"

**DTO:**

```
export class MetricsDTO {
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
}
```

**Service**

```
async getRevenue(metricClause: Partial<MetricsDTO>) {
    if (Object.keys(metricClause).length == 0) {
        var rev = await this.bookingsModel.aggregate([
            { $group: { _id: null, amount: { $sum: '$GrossAmount' } } }
        ])
    } else {
        var rev = await this.bookingsModel.aggregate([
            { $match: { TxnDate: { $gte: metricClause.fromDate, $lte: metricClause.toDate } } },
            { $group: { _id: null, amount: { $sum: '$GrossAmount' } } }
        ])
    }
    return rev[0].amount;
}
```

**Payload**

```
{
    "fromDate": "2019-10-24",
    "toDate": "2019-10-25"
}
```

Comment: Remember second stage $group gets data from first $match stage. So, you defines field TxnDate, and that stage data now going to $group stage. So, what I want to say make sure you have access $GrossAmount field in group stage. If you need dot notation than you can go with $_id.GrossAmount.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the aggreage causing the exception, this line causes the error, because you didn't check if the rev is null or not.

```
   return rev[0].amount;
```

So to handle null, you can:

```
if (rev && rev[0]) {
  return rev[0].amount;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did this help you?